# Hide the 'no category' in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, categories, taxonomy

I have a product page with a filter in it. I want to hide the 'no category' text if there is no category.

```
<?php wp_list_categories(array('taxonomy' => 'products', 'orderby' => 'order', 'title_li' => '', 'child_of' => ($term->parent==0) ? $term->term_id : $term->parent)); ?>
```

How can I implement it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `show_option_none` to your arguments array and set it to an empty string:

```
<?php wp_list_categories(array('show_option_none' => '', 'taxonomy' => 'products', 'orderby' => 'order', 'title_li' => '', 'child_of' => ($term->parent==0) ? $term->term_id : $term->parent)); ?>
```

You might also want to rewrite your code a little so it's easier to debug and not one long line, e.g.:

```
<?php 

$args = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'products', 
    'orderby' => 'order', 
    'title_li' => '', 
    'child_of' => ( $term->parent == 0 ) ? $term->term_id : $term->parent
    'show_option_none' => '', 
);

wp_list_categories( $args ); 

?>
```